# What SDL tools run as part of Microsoft's CloudBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, security

Does CloudBuild run any Security Development Lifecycle (SDL) tools as part of their daily build?

As part of the security review of our project, I am supposed to run a variety of SDL tools on our solution which include BinSkim, FxCop, Policheck etc. among other checks.

We have a daily CRON job which basically checks the integrity of the build using CloudBuild and apprises us of any failures.

Some SDL tools that I know that run as part of the CloudBuild as CredScan which scan for any coding standard violations.

I was wondering if there is a way of finding out the SDL tools that run as part of the CloudBuild?

Comment: Yes this one. This was the link that I referred to https://www.1eswiki.com/wiki/CloudBuild_Overview

Comment: @mjwills The security review requires that I ensure that my project passes the test for certain tools including FxCop, Policheck etc. If CloudBuild already runs these tools, I won't have to run them explicitly.

Comment: Also, CloudBuild supports Buddy builds and not full build. A full build is the default build platform for Build Framework and runs a lot of SDL tools. I was wondering what SDL tools would CloudBuild support or in general Buddy build frameworks support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it was meant to be posted on Microsoft's internal SO instance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the tooling & hyperlinks mentioned in the question are internal to Microsoft and should have been posted in internal support channels.